# Creating a random array from a matrix

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following code for returning an array from a matrix, but it does not work. I was wondering if you could help me correct it. Thanks a bunch.

```
import numpy as np

class city:
    def  __init__(self,A,route):
        self.A=A
        self.route=route

    def  distance(self):
        A = np.array([[ 0,  10,    20,  30],[10,   0,    25,  20],[20,  25,     0,  15],[30,  20,    15,   0]])
        return A

    def route(self,A):
        route = random.sample(A, len(A[:,0]))
        return route

ob=city(route)
print(ob.route)
```

Expected output:

```
[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)]
```

Comment: can you add the input you give for route? Also you are not passing the parameter A for the class city

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the random nodes to visit next and remove the chosen node from the nodes to be visited list (`nodes`).

Finally create the cell address based on the current and next node pair values.

It makes sure each node is picked only once (one in each row and each column) and also not going back to the same node (`a_ii`)

```
import numpy as np
import random 

class city:
    def  __init__(self):
        self.distance()

    def  distance(self):
        self.A = np.array([[ 0,  10,    20,  30],[10,   0,    25,  20],[20,  25,     0,  15],[30,  20,    15,   0]])
        self.B = np.array([[random.randint(0,1) for j in range(self.A.shape[0])] for i in range(self.A.shape[1])])

    def route(self):
        n=self.B.shape[0]
        nodes=list(range(n))
        route = [nodes.pop(random.sample(range(n-i),1)[0]) for i in range(n)]
        return [(route[i],route[i+1]) for i in range(n-1)]

ob=city() 
print(ob.route())
```

output:

```
[(1, 0), (0, 3), (3, 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I want to pickup a cell from the matrix randomly as an array.

Comment: Hence, I want to return cell index in the array instead of its values. Also without repetition.

Comment: Guess, you want a random route; find my updated code. Accept the answer, if it satisfies your requirement

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your prompt reply. I have the cell index too.

Comment: Output must be like the following:

Comment: [(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)]

Comment: Can you add the details about what repetition, which you dont want

Comment: Conditions: pickup just 1 cell in each row and column. (i,j) subject to i not equal to j. And finally, (1,2) or (2,1).

Comment: I think, first two conditions are satisfied in my current solution. What is the third one (1,2) or (2,1)?

Comment: The third one refers to avoid creating two paths between two nodes. Also illustrates the solution as its cell address.

Comment: then my current solution satisfies all three conditions.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It works. But I have changed it to work based on a random matrix. But it returns 'AttributeError'. I was wondering if you could help me.

Comment: Hav updated my solution. Kindly accept the solution if it solved your problem

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. Now I want to add the following conditions: get just a 1 in first row and column and in the other rows and columns get just a 1 .

Comment: Could you please ask this as a separate question. We can take it up.

Answer (score 0):

import numpy as np
import random
class city:
    def  **init**(self):
        self.distance()

```
def  distance(self):
    self.A = np.array([[ 0,  10,    20,  30],[10,   0,    25,  20],[20,  25,     0,  15],[30,  20,    15,   0]])
    self.B = [[random.randint(0,1) for j in range(self.A.shape[0])] for i in range(self.A.shape[1])]

def route(self):
    n=self.B.shape[0]
    nodes=list(range(n))
    route = [nodes.pop(random.sample(range(n-i),1)[0]) for i in range(n)]
    return [(route[i],route[i+1]) for i in range(n-1)]
```

ob=city()
print(ob.route())